# net::ERR-INVALID-CHUNKED-ENCODING

Tags: java, html, web

I have an unusual error that only happen on certain PCs when requesting URL on any page on my web application.
The error is:

> *net::ERR-INVALID-CHUNKED-ENCODING*

The error not always happened, but I could say 2 out of 3 request is bound to error.
The application is Spring MVC jar which is deployed on a web server.

Any help please?

Comment: What Servlet container or app server you are using? What is the View technology ?

Comment: I am using Spring boot (v1.2.1 release), servlet container is embedded Apache Tomcat/8.0.15, view is Spring MVC with Thymeleaf (v2.1.4 release). hope this enough.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem in my Java/Spring/Hibernate web application. It was observed in Chrome browser and Postman client, but wasn't in Firefox (it seems more tolerant of http specs violations).

Rest API controller had to respond a JSON containing list of entities from DB. It appeared that there was circular dependency in entities. When this entity was serialised it caused StackOverflowError which in turn closed connection unexpectedly during response transmission. Here is how it looked from server side:

```
10:42:08.665 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] ERROR com.myproject.rest.common.GlobalErrorHandler - Error while performing REST call org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: 
com.myproject.domain2.Device["compoundDevice"]- 
>com.myproject.domain2.Device["compoundDevice"]->com.myproject.domain2.Device["compoundDevice"]->com.myproject.domain2.Device["compoundDevice"]->com.myproject.domain2.Device["compoundDevice"]->com.myproject.domain2.Device["compoundDevice"]->com.myproject.domain2.Device["compoundDevice"]->com.myproject.domain2.Device["compoundDevice"]->com.myproject.domain2.Device["compoundDevice"]-
....
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017) ~[?:?]
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2415) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.20]
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:863) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.20]
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.20]
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1186) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.20]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:773) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1] 
...
```

Comment: In my case it was also a circular dependency.  Calling Spring Boot application  rest controller from Chrome yielded the "ERR-INVALID-CHUNKED-ENCODING" exception. I had recently introduced a new entity with a circular dependency between it and the parent. Adding the jsonignore annotation on the child reference to the parent fixed it for me.